# SQL VM Azure - Connecting via SSMS 'Security'

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have been queried by one of our 3rd party programmers. We are using a SQL Azure VM for the storage of some data.

The programmer has questioned in connecting to a SQL VM using SSMS, is the username and password encrypted or is the login passed as plain text?

Regards,

James

Comment: ``SSMS uses OLE DB and will not show your username`` http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/how-secure-is-the-traffic-with-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: i am sure ,it is encrypted and remeber reading the same on SO.One way to test is fire up network monitor and try connecting through ssms:https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=4865